# Enable PHP support in PHPStorm Mavericks

Tags: php, phpstorm

To begin, I am not using MAMP or any LAMP.

I have PHPStorm and I want to add my php installation as an interpreter. When I choose the correct folder: `"/usr/local/php5"` or `"/usr/local/php5/bin"`, PHPStorm gives me an error: PHP version: not installed.

However, both via the browser or the command line (`php -i`), both of my php installations are the same and the php.ini location for both is located at:

```
/usr/local/php5/lib
```

Why is PHPStorm not recognizing my PHP installation ? What am I missing ?

**Edit1:**

[image]

Comment: You need PHP with FCGI.

Comment: PhpStorm version used?

Comment: Not a PS user, but are your PHP version settings in the editor different from the PHP version? NetBeans gives an option for this, but I don't think it would complain if the two were different.

Comment: @LazyOne I am using the last one, 7.1.3

Comment: Are you sure it's not just complaining about Xdebug?

Comment: @Jack I updated the post with a screenshot

Comment: **Please try v8 EAP** (latest build was released few hours ago) -- it has fix for http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-23045 -- **possibly** the same as yours.

Comment: @LazyOne It doesn't work in EAP unfortunately...

Comment: No other ideas then, sorry.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: It was an error with the phpstorm version if I recall correctly and was fixed in the next one

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command in the terminal and use the output path as the path of your interpreter.

```
which php
```

Comment: I get /usr/local/php5/bin/php and when I put this path, it doesn't change anything (with or without the php at the end)

Comment: You have to make it readable so PHPStorm can read it. Try "sudo chmod +r /usr/local/php5/bin/php"

Comment: In "PHP Home" input you should write the folder not the full path. Write only /usr/local/php5/bin. If doesn't work either can you try with chmod 777.

Comment: I know thank you. No unfortunately with chmod 777 I still get the same error.